# Process list in parallel with makefile

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I have a list of around 20 URLs, and I wish to do the following commands on each of them **in parallel**:

1. Download file at URL
2. Unzip file
3. Run a local tool on

How can I define a task for this with a `makefile`?

I understand the targets and dependencies thing, but it seems overkill to make 20+ targets.
Is there a way I can specify an array, and then `foreach` over them but in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is your friend.

The easiest way is breaking into small makefiles and running a parallel for loop on them. Here is [a similar example](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__download_10_images_for_each_of_the_past_30_days) where they download 10 images from different URLs in parallel.